# How to keep BitmapShader not drawing outside the image

Tags: android, android-canvas, bitmapshader

I have a custom view that is showing an image inside a shape.
I used `BitmapShader` to fit my image into the shape with `TileMode` is CLAMP
Now I have a problem that when I am moving my image (using `setLocalMatrix` method) it make my image become terrible. 
here is my image when moving around:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
BitmapShader shader=new BitmapShader(sbmp, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
Matrix currMatrix = new Matrix(this.getMatrix());
currMatrix.postTranslate(currX, currY); 
shader.setLocalMatrix(currMatrix);
mpaint.setShader(shader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate image with instead of localMatrix

```
int i = canvas.save();
canvas.translate(currX, currY);
//Here draw image
canvas.restoreToCount(i);
```